Docker CMD could not find executable
My Dockerfile to build Go executable and pack into container looks like:
FROM golang:1.23.2 AS builder

COPY . /github.com/vbulash/auth/src/
WORKDIR /github.com/vbulash/auth/src/

RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o ./bin/auth_server cmd/grpc_server/main.go

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /github.com/vbulash/auth/src/bin/auth_server .
RUN ls -la .

CMD ["./auth_server"]

Command RUN ls -la . is not required for docker CLI, but under Github Actions shows just one entry - auth_server
CLI for build and run:
docker buildx build -t go_app -f Dockerfile .
docker run -p 50051:50051 -t go_app

Run ends with error:
exec ./auth_server: no such file or directory
How to drop this error?

Your Dockerfile works as shown, so there must be something else going on. Create a [mre] to demonstrate the problem. Other than the fact that you should not use filename arguments with the go command, this seems unrelated to the Go language.

My guess is that the copied build product is not executable, since COPY was not used with chmod. See Copying files with execute permissions in Docker Image

Mixing a Debian-based Go toolchain container and an Alpine-based runtime often doesn't work this way.  Does using an Alpine-based toolchain in the first stage work better?
